# __import__() works with python3.6.5 but does not work with python3.7.3

Tags: import, python-3.6, python-3.7

The following script works fine with python3.6.5 but failed with python3.7.3 in windows 10 (home edition):

```
mod = __import__(pth, globals(), locals(), ['*'])
```

With python3.6.5 and python3.7.3, pth, globals() and locals() are almost same as follows (mPayment.py locates in scripts/demo):

```
pth       ==>  "scripts.demo.mPayment"

locals()  ==>   {'pth': 'scripts.demo.mPayment', 'self': <bop.bopModule.MasterModule object at 0x000002586EC3EC88>}

globals() ==>   {...}   #globals() has nothing to do with "scripts.demo.mPayment"
```

But with python3.7.3, I got exception:

```
Exception occurs in importing module demo.mPayment.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\xxx\b\Module.py", line 50, in _init
    mod = __import__(pth, globals(), locals(), ['*'])
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scripts.demo'
```

Anyone knows what is going on with the `__import__()` script in python 3.7.3 since it works with python3.6.5. Thanks a lot for your help.

ouyang

Answer (score 0):

I just move the project root path in sys.path to the first one, then `__import__()` can find those modules.